# Unknown bluetooth device connected to my MacOS

Tags: bluetooth

I just discovered a weird device connected to my macOS.

The device is called "Nets", it is found in the bluetooth menu bar, but not if I open bluetooth preferences.

Any clue what this might be? I've been reading a lot about bluetooth exploits recently.

P.s. I've been driving in a car (without any BT devices), and it's been connected the whole trip.

[image]
[image]

### Update:

After clicking disconnect, it lagged for 4-5 seconds (strange, normally it does not when disconnecting devices), and then disappeared.

Comment: That MAC belongs to BlueGiga technologies  they make wifi radios https://www.adminsub.net/mac-address-finder/886b . The only thing that comes up for Nets and bluetooth is an Ingenico wireless chip & pin device (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAb5rOWJH7Y) Do you use your phone to accept payments?

Comment: Thanks @iain! I was (before I drove) connected to a wifi bluetooth radio, although I was not connected, when I came back to the car. Funny thing is: I was initially connected on my phone - not my laptop. Does Apple somehow share this data between devices?

Comment: I wouldn't expect your apple profile to share bluetooth between devices, typically a pairing is between two distinct devices. Also to clarify I meant 'radios' as in wifi chipsets not like as in DABs, though their chips are used in audio equipment, healthcare equipment and other device classes. It's most likely something connecting to you in error I would expect.